# How to read character from console in c++?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, character

I'm struggling with reading characters from console in c++.
Here is what I tried to do:

```
char x;
char y; 
char z;

cout<<"Please enter your string: ";
string s;
getline(cin,s);
istringstream is(s);

is>> x >> y >> z;
```

The problem is if the user enter something like this "1 20 100":

```
x will get 1
y will get 2
z will get 0
```

What I want to get is x = 1; y = 20; z = 100;

Anybody has suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to read characters but integers.

```
int x;
int y; 
int z;

cout<<"Please enter your string: ";
string s;
getline(cin,s);
istringstream is(s);

is>> x >> y >> z;
```

Comment: I want to read by character because i want to save memory. Character takes only 1 byte (which is good enough for my program) vs integer 4 bytes.

Comment: So when you want z = 100, but want z to be a character, what do you mean?  Do you mean ascii character 100?

Comment: If you really want, then use `short int` (which may or may not be less than 4 bytes, depending on your compiler and architecture), but I guarantee you that if you're having trouble with something this fundamental, you are a long way away from needing to worry about optimizing to save 9 bytes of memory on the stack.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that at all. But if you insist, you can use a short, 2 bytes long and most likely the proper overload is defined.

Comment: lets say with z = 100, i wanna treat it as integer, not a character. By using character type instead of integer, i could save 3 bytes. Do u get my idea?

Comment: yes, because short int also takes 4 bytes like int (for my compiler), i can't use it.

Comment: @tsubasa We understand. We're saying it's not worth the hassle. This is what's called "premature optimization". You are causing yourself a an unnecessary headache and making your code confusing to save a few bytes that don't matter.

Comment: the string s takes more than 12 bytes

Comment: @tsubasa: Why do you feel the need to save such tiny space? If any, the compiler might pad some stack variables for alignment anyway. `string` dynamically allocates, takes up a bit more space, streams in general aren't afraid to use stack variables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there. `operator>>()` is the formatted extraction operator. Change the variables from type `char` to type `int` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to read in integers.  You could do:

```
int x, y, z;

cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
cin >> x >> y >> z;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting those results is that since x,y and z are chars, when you use istringstream it reads the first character into x, it skips the space and reads the character '2' into y and the next character is '0' and that goes into z.

```
char x, y, z;
cout << "Please enter three integers: ";
cin >> x >> y >> z;
```

If that doesn't work, just use ints because trying to find a workaround to use chars instead of ints to save memory is worrying about the wrong thing here.